# Php Setup was messed up

Tags: php, ubuntu-17.10

I did this command on ubuntu `echo php phpinfo(); > a.txt`
and this changed the php command on my pc. So whenever I run `which php` I get `php () {> a.txt}`

Comment: Please `ls -la` in the directory you did the original command. There will probably be a file a.txt. If so, removing it might fix this

Comment: A restart to the computer solved the problem.

Comment: I am now looking for a.txt to delete it

Comment: if you want to be sure: `sudo find <directory> -name a.text` replace <directory> with a path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this we need:

1. Restart the computer
2. `find a.text` and delete it